# Bash function to ls absolute path (but behaves like ls)

Tags: bash, ls

I am trying to write a bash function that follows the same behavior as ls, but it displays the full path instead of the relative one. What I have written so far is the following:

```
ls_abs()
{
    if [ -z "$1" ]
    then
        ls -d -1 $PWD/*
    else
        ls -d -1 $PWD/${1}
    fi
}
```

Calling `ls_abs` seems to work just fine, but when I try to call it with a wildcard argument (`ls_abs thisdir/that*/anotherdir/*.log`, for example), for some reason it will only output one line. Can someone help me to understand what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You only use one arg `${1}`. You have to iterate over all arguments and prepend all arguments with PWD.

Comment: The glob is expanded into multiple arguments by the shell before `ls_abs` is even called. The function receives multiple arguments; the unexpanded argument isn't passed directly to `ls` for it to expand.

Comment: PSA: Please [do not use this pattern in scripts](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell automatically expands your wildcard expression, before it calls the `ls_abs` function, so it receives multiple arguments, and the `${1}` is the first one, thus you are seeing only one line output.

You would have two options here:

1. Put the wildcard argument in quotes

```sh
ls_abs "thisdir/that*/anotherdir/*.log"
```

2. Use `$@` to handle all passed positional params.

```
ls_abs() {
  ls -d -1 "$@"
}
ls_abs thisdir/that*/anotherdir/*.log
```